# Cannot configure organization for Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Outlook. Try to configure the organization again

Tags: microsoft-outlook, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm getting the following error when configuring CRM for Outlook:

> Cannot configure organization for Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Outlook. Try to configure the organization again

Below is the log file:

> The entity name ='team' with namemapping= 'Logical' was not found in the metadataCache. at Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an infrastructure or Server performance issue on CRM online side as discussed in [this Community thread](https://community.dynamics.com/365/f/dynamics-365-general-forum/362223/error-while-configuring-crm-with-outlook-client) (replied by Microsoft employee) and should have been resolved.

> it was happening since there was a perf issue on the server side. Now the issue has been fixed. The fix has been deployed to the server side. The original issue should not happen again.